# Essence of Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

Weierstrass approximation theorem is a quite strong theorem,even stronger than the Taylor's theorem because:

**Statement:Suppose $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function then $\exists$ a sequence of polynomials $\{P_n\}$ converging uniformly to $f$.**

1.It is an approximation supported by uniform convergence.

2.It can approximate any continuous function not necessarily differentiable/smooth one.

So,I want to understand its essence properly.In most of the books like Kumaresan and Rudin,a very mechanical proof is given;the proof obviously will not occur in mind naturally(unless he is a genius).Is there any proof that will come in mind naturally and quite intuitive and brings out the essence of that theorem?[Please note that I do not know Riemann Integrals,so the proof should not involve these things.]
       Also I want to understand why the domain set must be a compact interval in $\mathbb R$,i.e of the form $[a,b]$.Why is the assumption essential?Give me an example where we cannot approximate a function because domain is not compact.

Comment: About the last question: Trigonometric polynomials are bounded, so any unbounded continuous function is an immediate counterexample... Compactness is mainly needed to enforce boundedness.

Comment: As for the essence of the Theorem, you are unfortunatelly asking us to explain in very low level terms a Theorem whose essence, in my oppinion, is actually a much more deeper and more complicated than it... To me the essence of this theorem is that it is just a particular case of Stone--Weierstarss Theorem, which is a very general result.

Comment: what is the generalized version?

Comment: I did not understand what N.S. said about trigonometric polynomial because do we require trigonometric polynomial in stone weierstrass?

Comment: Trigonometric polynomials have nothing to do with Stone Weierstarss, those were two completely unrelated comments.... That's why I posted them separatelly...... Just try to approximate $f(x)=x$ or any unbounded function on $(0, \infty)$ by trigonometric polynomials, and you'll see why you cannot.

Comment: Stone--Weierstrass says that "Suppose X is a compact Hausdorff space and $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ which contains a non-zero constant function. Then $A$ is dense in $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ if and only if it separates points." The set of trigonometric polynomials satisfies this property..

Comment: Stone proved many generalisations of Weierstrass's theorem, one of which was quoted by N.S. Here's Stone's [remarkable paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3029750?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) on the subject.

Comment: In essence, for $X=[a,b]$ a compact interval, The Stone--Weierstrass theorem basically says that, if you have a set $A$ of real valued continuous functions, which is non-zero and closed under addition, multiplication and scalar multiplication, then each continuous function on $[a,b]$ can be approximated uniformly by an element in $A$ IF AND ONLY IF, for each pair of points $a \leq x <y  \leq b$ you can find some $f \in A$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$.... And to me this is the essence:" There is a much more general and subtle reason why you get such an approximation", but a deep reason.

Comment: Also, on the topic of comparing Taylor's theorem and Weierstrass's theorem, Weierstrass's theorem is trickier to apply in many cases, as the construction in the proof is complicated, leading to very large degree approximating polynomials. Plus, it doesn't play well with derivatives; in general the derivative of an approximating polynomial will not be at all close to the derivative of the function it's approximating.

Comment: I have edited this question a bit.

Comment: Weierstrass approximation theorem is neither stronger nor weaker than the Taylor theorem.

Comment: Why do you say so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ f:(0;1] \rightarrow \mathbb R\ $ be such that
$$ \forall_{x\in(0;1]}\quad f(x)\ :=\ \cos\left(\frac \pi x\right) $$

Then
$$ \forall_{n=1}^\infty\quad f\left(\frac 1n\right)\ =\ (-1)^n $$

Let $\ g:(0;1]\rightarrow\infty\ $ be continuous and such that

$$ \forall_{n=1}^\infty\quad \left|g\left(\frac 1n\right)-(-1)^n\right| < \frac 12 $$

hence
$$ \forall_{n=1}^\infty\quad g\left(\frac 1{2\cdot n-1}\right) < -\frac 12
        \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad g\left(\frac 1{2\cdot n}\right) > \frac 12    $$

It follows that
$$ \forall_{n=1}^\infty\,\ \exists_
      {x_n\in\left[\frac 1{n+1};\frac 1n\right]}
              \,\ g(x_n)\ =\ 0 $$

Thus, function $\ g\ $ has infinitely many roots hence it cannot be a polynomial.
We see that there does not exist a polynomial $g$ which approximates $\ f\ $
within $\ \frac 12,\ $, the uniform distance is $\ |g-f|\ \ge \frac 12.$

Answer (score 2):

No bounded continuous function from $\mathbb R$ into itself (other than a constant) can be approximated uniformly on $\mathbb R$ by polynomials. This is because any non-constant polynomial $p$ has the property $|p(x)| \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. In particular $\sin\, x$ can  be approximated by polynomials uniformly on any interval of the type $[-N,N]$ but not on the whole real line.

Comment: Indeed, non-constant polynomials in $\ \mathbb R\ $ are unbounded, they don't even belong to the algebra of bounded functions.